# Validate form before submit in php with the routes

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, routes

i must validate a form before submit, in this code I use routes, so i can't use $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] (maybe) someone can help me please?

```
<form name="user" action="index.php?action=save-report" method="post">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="report">Quante persone ci sono secondo te? </label>
     <br>
     <input type="number" id="report" name="report"  maxlength="180"  style="width: 5%" class="form-control" required >
   </div>
   <br>

   <button class="btn btn-primary">Invia</button>
   <input type="hidden" id="user__token" name="user[_token]" value="">
   <br>
</form>
```

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please elaborate what you mean by "I use routes so I can't use superglobals"?

Comment: @ArSeN in the action of the form I redirect to the routes file, but i would like sent a message (for example if the user write something wrong) without refresh the page

Comment: Validate before submit ? use jquery or javascript I am sure there are plenty solutions around stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to validate without refreshing is Javascript, just add a onchange attribute to the input and validate through js.

```
<input type="text" onchange="validate(this)" required>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Invia">

function validate(elem) {
   if (elem.value != "Ciao") {
      elem.classList.add("notValid"); //for example red border or red label...
      document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
   else {
      elem.classList.remove("notValid");
      document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you already use html5 take a look on [html5 form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation):
Most modern browsers will validate your input before able to post it to your server, without the need of javascript.

I.e. if you want your input to allow minimal 1 and maximum 180 persons to enter, you could use:

```
<input type="number" id="report" name="report" min="1" max="180"  style="width: 5%" class="form-control" required >
```

See explanation of [min](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/min) and [max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/max) attributes.